# Prove $L^p$ is $L^p(\mathbb{N},P(\mathbb{N}),\mu_c)$ where $\mu_c$ is the counting measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $1\leq p <\infty$ and define $L^p$ as the space of all sequence such that $(s_n)$ of real number such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|s_n|<\infty$. If $(s_n)\in L^p$ we define:

$$||(s_n)||_p=(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|s_n|^p)^{(\frac{1}{p})}\tag1$$

Prove $L^p$ is $L^p(\mathbb{N},P(\mathbb{N}),\mu_c)$ where $\mu_c$ is the counting measure, in other words:

$$L^p=\{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:\int|f|^pd\mu_c<\infty\}\tag2$$

**My attempt:**

As $\mu_c$ is discrete then $\sum|s_n|^p=\displaystyle\int|f|^pd\mu_c<\infty$

Moreover, $L^p=\{(s_n):\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}|s_n|^p<\infty\}$

As $(s_n)$ is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ then

$$L^p=\{f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} : \displaystyle\int|f|^pd\mu_c <\infty\}$$

Is correct this?

Comment: Normally the sequence space is denoted $\ell^p$, and $L^p$ is used for $L^p([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \lambda)$ with Lebesgue measure, and classes of function (modulo equality a.e.). They're isometric though.

Comment: It's basically correct. But why do we have $\sum_n|s_n|^p=\int|f|^pd\mu_c$?